# How to use XSLT to convert a simple piece of XML

Tags: xslt

How can you convert

```
<person>
   <personFirstName>FirstName</personFirstName>
   <personLastName>LastName</personLastName>
   <personAge>40</personAge>
</person>
```

to

```
<person>
   <name>
      <first>FirstName</first>
      <last>LastName</last>
   </name>
   <age>40</age>
</person>
```

using XSLT, moreover, if the input XML is a collection of person nodes, like so:

```
<persons>
   <person>
       ...
   </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that uses the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule/template. This solutions adheres as much as possible to the "push-style" processing. Explanation is also provided.

Comment: What if all these nodes: personFirstName, personLastName, personAge are optional in xml? And I would need to produce the new structure only if one of these elements is present. This becomes tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A "push-style" solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="personFirstName">
  <name>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="renameWrapped"
        select=".|../personLastName"/>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="personFirstName" mode="renameWrapped">
  <first><xsl:apply-templates/></first>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="personLastName" mode="renameWrapped">
  <last><xsl:apply-templates/></last>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="personAge">
  <age><xsl:apply-templates/></age>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="personLastName"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <personFirstName>FirstName</personFirstName>
        <personLastName>LastName</personLastName>
        <personAge>40</personAge>
    </person>
    <person>
        <personFirstName>FirstName2</personFirstName>
        <personLastName>LastName2</personLastName>
        <personAge>100</personAge>
    </person>
</persons>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<persons>
   <person>
      <name>
         <first>FirstName</first>
         <last>LastName</last>
      </name>
      <age>40</age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>
         <first>FirstName2</first>
         <last>LastName2</last>
      </name>
      <age>100</age>
   </person>
</persons>
```

Explanation:

1. **Using and overriding the identity rule/template** for wrapping and renaming of elements.
2. **The elements to be wrapped are renamed in mode** `renameWrapped`.
3. **The `personAge` element is renamed in a non-moded template** that overrides the identity rule for elements named `personAge`.

Comment: Dimitre, what do you mean by shorter? Shorter than what?

Comment: @DevNull: Good question. Initially my code was shorter than yours, but since then I edited it and now both are aproximately the same length. I edited my answer again and now the phrase in question has been deleted. Thanks for the good catch.

Comment: Ahh, I thought I missed something else.

Answer (score 2):

It should be very easy. You can try to:

- match `person` then open `name`, apply templates, close `name`, open `age`, get value from `personAge`, close `age`
- match `personFirstName`, open `first`, get value, close `first`
- same as `personFirstName` for `personLastName`

I think 3 templates wihtout loops should be enough. Try it!

Comment: +1 for a good description on what to do and for "Try it!". I shouldn't have been so quick to answer with a complete stylesheet. It's hard to resist though.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the identity transform and overriding it when needed.

**Sample XML**

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <personFirstName>FirstName</personFirstName>
    <personLastName>LastName</personLastName>
    <personAge>40</personAge>
  </person>
  <person>
    <personFirstName>FirstName2</personFirstName>
    <personLastName>LastName2</personLastName>
    <personAge>100</personAge>
  </person>
</persons>
```

**Sample XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity Transform-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <person>
      <name>
        <first><xsl:apply-templates select="personFirstName"/></first>
        <last><xsl:apply-templates select="personLastName"/></last>
      </name>
      <age><xsl:apply-templates select="personAge"/></age>
    </person>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="personFirstName|personLastName|personAge">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<persons>
   <person>
      <name>
         <first>FirstName</first>
         <last>LastName</last>
      </name>
      <age>40</age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>
         <first>FirstName2</first>
         <last>LastName2</last>
      </name>
      <age>100</age>
   </person>
</persons>
```

Comment: +1, thanks for giving some value to this post. I've been a bit sarscastic :) in my answer.